# Touch screen implemetation for a game 

Tags: java-me, touch

We have created a small game, it's working fine in devices, now we want to implement the touch functionality.

Can anybody give me a good solution to implement a touch for this game? I need full touch.

Programming language: J2ME

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try Series 40 Touch & Type. [Check this link for sdk](http://blogs.forum.nokia.com/blog/nokia-developer-news/2011/01/12/try-touch-and-type-series-40-sdk-version-1.0) also you can find examples for this device in touch type.